# How do I use localStorage to remember a user’s name

Tags: javascript, dom, local-storage, remember-me

This code has been checked for errors and none were detected. But, when it runs, it alerts null.

For Sololearners my code bit: https://code.sololearn.com/WOv1cF0EewdB/?ref=app

Why is this?*

```
window.onload = function() {

let reload_interval= setInterval(rel, 120000);

if (localStorage.getItem('visit') !== true) { 


    let username = prompt('Enter your name:');

    if (confirm('Do you want to be known as ' + username + ' from now on?')) {

        localStorage.setItem('name', username);

    } else {

        username = prompt('OK then, enter your name:');

        if (confirm('Do you want to be known as ' + username + 'from now on?')) {

            localStorage.setItem('name', username);

        }

    }

    localStorage.setItem('visit', true);

}

if (localStorage.getItem('visit') === true) {

    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('name');
    
     alert('Hello, ' + localStorage.getItem('name'));

}


};

function clearLocalStorage() {
if (confirm('Do you want to clear current username data?')) {
  localStorage.clear();
    alert('Cleared');
}
}
```

*jQuery answers are OK

Comment: Wrong, there is an error.  *"Error: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."*  It's in the lower right hand corner of your SoloLearners page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting a hello alert is because you are checking `getItem`'s return value with `=== true` and `!== true`.

`setItem` will convert your value to `string`, so `localStorage.getItem('visit') === true` will **never** be true

If you want to check if the user has visited the page, you should use `=== "true"`(visited) and `!== "true"`(not visited) since it returns `string`.